# How to acess imageview defined in adapter?

Tags: java, android

I have an imageview defined in Recyclerview's Adapter on View holder in Android.I want to access that imageview to my activity for setting image programatically.How i can do it?

Comment: Where' your code?

Comment: Set Image resource or url of image in model class of your list item.

Comment: please provide the code you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an adapter ImageRecyclerAdapter class:

```
public class ImageRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

     public interface ImageViewInterface {

           void onImageViewLoaded(ImageView imageView);
         } 

final ImageViewInterface imageViewInterface;

public ImageRecyclerAdapter(ImageViewInterface imageViewInterface) {

    this.imageViewInterface = imageViewInterface;

}

//in the onBindViewHolder method

public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   imageViewInterface.onImageViewLoaded(holder.imageView);

  }
}
```

Then in your activity you can instantiate and use it like

```
ImageRecyclerAdapter imageRecyclerAdapter = new ImageRecyclerAdapter(new ImageRecyclerAdapter.ImageViewInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onImageViewLoaded(ImageView imageView) {
            //do what ever with your image view
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually i don't want to extend the view holder in my activity because in my adapter so many things happening.i want to use only one image view from there. your solution was good but if there is any other easy way to do this then let me know

Comment: Isn't it will return only one image?

Comment: You can use the same code and send the image view when you create it , instead of during/inside the onbind viewholder. If you can tell me what you mean exacly not wanting to extend the view holder i can modify my answer